# JS Console iterate through URLs

Tags: javascript, url, console, intervals, persistent

I have this JS script that iterates over a list of URLs on the same domain and I want to store some data from them.
What I want is to do it from a browser, so for example I set an interval that stores my data on localStorage and then takes a link (from localstorage as well) and changes the window location to that URL.
So, what I want is for that interval to persist even after I change the URL.
Is this possible

Thanks in advance, have a nice one!

Answer (score 0):

No, that particular approach is not possible. A redirect resets all JavaScript variables, including timeouts.

What you could do is grab the next URL from localStorage, set the localStorage to contain the URL after that, and then redirect to the URL you just grabbed and repeat.